# Python code error while using functions

Tags: python

I have this code I want it to ask the question as many times as it needs to until a yes or no answer is given

```
def teacheraskno():
teacher = input("Are you a teacher? yes and no answers only! > ")
if teacher == "no" or "yes".lower():
    if teacher == "no".lower():
        start()
    if teacher == "yes".lower():
        teacheraskyes()
else:
    print ("Please enter yes and no answers only!")
    teacheraskno()

def teacheraskyes():
if teacher == "yes".lower(): 
    password = input("What is the Password? > ")
if password =="123".lower(): 
    print ("ACCESS GRANTED!")
    classname = input("what class would you like to view? 1, 2 or 3 > ")

    f = open(classname + ".txt", 'r') #opens the class file
    file_contents = f.read()
    print (file_contents)
    f.close()


teacher = input("Are you a teacher? yes and no answers only! > ")
if teacher == "no" or "yes".lower():
    if teacher == "no".lower():
        start()
    if teacher == "yes".lower():
        teacheraskyes()
    else:
        print ("Please enter yes and no answers only!")
        teacheraskno()
```

I keep getting this error

```
==============================Math Revision Quiz================================
Are you a teacher? yes and no answers only! > bla
Please enter yes and no answers only!
Are you a teacher? yes and no answers only! > yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\My Documents\Ben Atia CA A453\Python Code\Python Code 1.py", line 142, in <module>
    teacheraskno()
  File "S:\My Documents\Ben Atia CA A453\Python Code\Python Code 1.py", line 118, in teacheraskno
    teacheraskyes()
  File "S:\My Documents\Ben Atia CA A453\Python Code\Python Code 1.py", line 125, in teacheraskyes
    if password =="123".lower(): #if the password is correct it will let the teacher view the code
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'password' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You should be using `teacher.lower()` instead of `"yes".lower()` or `"no".lower()`. `"no"` and `"yes"` are already lowercase...

Also you should compare like this `teacher.lower() == "yes" or teacher.lower() == "no"`

Comment: Please don't use `123` as password and please don't hard-code it! :-/

Comment: Please format your code and traceback.

Comment: In Python indentation is part of language syntax. Please, fix it so whitespace would actually denote code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You should change this line

```
if teacher == "no" or "yes".lower():
```

To

```
if teacher.lower() not in ("no", "yes"):
```

As currently written, the expression doesn't mean what you think it does. If I add parentheses for emphasis, your expression actually reads as

```
if (teacher == "no") or ("yes".lower()):
```

The subexpression `"yes".lower()` will *always* yield `True`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure given your snippet's boken indentation, but here:

```
if teacher == "yes".lower(): 
    password = input("What is the Password? > ")
if password =="123".lower(): 
    print ("ACCESS GRANTED!")
```

you only define the `password` variable in the first `if` branch, but try to read it in both cases. So if `teacher` is not equal to "yes", `password` is not defined.

There are quite a few other problems with your code, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.lower` you could use `str.casefold()` before `input()`. This will make anything the user enters into lower case. Not only is this a validation but it allows you to write all your code in lowercase. For example:

```
teacher = str.casefold(input("Are you a teacher?"))
```

This should change anything the user enters lowercase and the res of your code could be written in lowercase without the `.lower()` function.